# Почему Uncaught TypeError: "x" is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null

**Uncaught TypeError: dropArea is null, хотя все объявлено и должно работать(**

```js
import React from 'react'
import "./DropArea.css"


const DropFileArea = () => {
    const dropArea = document.querySelector(".drag-area"),
dragText = dropArea.querySelector("header"),
button = dropArea.querySelector("button"),
input = dropArea.querySelector("input");
let file; 
button.onclick = ()=>{
  input.click(); 
}
input.addEventListener("change", function(){
 
  file = this.files[0];
  dropArea.classList.add("active");
  showFile(); 
});

dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", (event)=>{
  event.preventDefault(); 
  dropArea.classList.add("active");
  dragText.textContent = "Release to Upload File";
});

dropArea.addEventListener("dragleave", ()=>{
  dropArea.classList.remove("active");
  dragText.textContent = "Drag & Drop to Upload File";
});
dropArea.addEventListener("drop", (event)=>{
  event.preventDefault(); 
  file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
  showFile(); 
});
function showFile(){
  let fileType = file.type; 
  let validExtensions = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"]; 
  if(validExtensions.includes(fileType)){ 
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = ()=>{
      let fileURL = fileReader.result; 
    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }else{
    alert("This is not an Image File!");
    dropArea.classList.remove("active");
    dragText.textContent = "Drag & Drop to Upload File";
  }
}

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div class="drag-area">
                <div className='icon' ><i className='fas fa-cloud-upload-alt'></i></div>
                <header>Drag & Drop to Upload File</header>
                <span>OR</span>
                <button>Browse File</button>
                <input type="file" hidden/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default DropFileArea;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Я прошу прощения, Вы понимаете, что вы написали и в какой последовательности это будет работать? Как минимум, все document.querySelector, addEventListener должны быть удалены из компонента и переписаны на события реакта. В вашем случае `document.querySelector(".drag-area")` отрабатывает до того, как элемент с этим классом будет установлен в DOM, а позже может быть удален и заново установлен...

Comment: И еще момент про вашим addEventListener. Каждый вызов функции будет устанавливать обработчик событик(Не заменять, а добавлять еще одно). Посмотрите [как работает функциональный компонент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457575/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-react/1457948#1457948) и что будет происходить с учетом вот этого ответа про [addEventListener](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453279/#1453302)