# Почему при добавлении картинки через input и выводе ее на экран, она выводится 2 раза?

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть форма добавления картинки:

```
<div class="pic-container">
<div class="close-popup"></div>
<div id="dnd">
    <form action="<?= admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php wp_nonce_field('regauthor_upload_file'); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="registration_author" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?= get_permalink(); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="formNum" value="2" />
        <input id="fileElem" type="file" name="regauthor_upload_file" required />
        <label class="button" for="fileElem">Кликните или перетащите изображение</label>
    </form>
</div>
```

При добавлении картинки она с помощью js выводится на тут же в блоке div class="pic-container". Но при перетаскивании она нормально один раз выводится, а при добавлении через клик - 2 раза.
Вот js код:

```
dnd.addEventListener('drop', event => {

  event.preventDefault();

  dnd.dataset.over = false;

  const text = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");

  if (text) {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = text;
    picCont.appendChild(img);
  } else {

    var files = event.dataTransfer.files;

    [].map.call(files, file => {

      if (file.type.match(/^image/)) {

        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = file => {
            let img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = file.target.result;
            picCont.appendChild(img);
            dnd.style.display = 'none';
            closePopup.style.display = 'block';
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        inputImg.files = files;
        console.log(file);

      }

    })

  }
});

dnd.addEventListener('click', () => {
    inputImg.click();
    inputImg.addEventListener('change', event => {
        let curFiles = inputImg.files;
        console.log(curFiles.length);
        let reader = new FileReader();

        [].map.call(curFiles, file => {

          if (file.type.match(/^image/)) {

            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = file => {
              let img = document.createElement('img');
              img.src = file.target.result;
              picCont.appendChild(img);
              dnd.style.display = 'none';
              closePopup.style.display = 'block';
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            console.log(file);

          }

        })
    });
});
```

Comment: потому что на каждый клик добавляешь новый обработчик change

Comment: Про [добавление новых обработчиков и как с ними бороться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453279/1453302#1453302)