# Два раза срабатывает событие onClick

Tags: javascript, события

Есть одна панель и к ней реализована кнопка блокировки этой панели.

```
static lock = {
    querySelector: document.querySelector('.lock'),
    action () {
        let lockBtn = Toolbar.lock.querySelector;
        if (lockBtn.classList.contains('unlocked')) {
            lockBtn.classList.remove('unlocked');
            lockBtn.classList.add('locked');
            Toolbar.querySelector.removeEventListener("click", Toolbar.onClick);
            lockBtn.addEventListener("click", Toolbar.lock.action);
        }
        else {
            lockBtn.classList.remove('locked');
            lockBtn.classList.add('unlocked');
            lockBtn.removeEventListener("click", Toolbar.lock.action);
            Toolbar.querySelector.addEventListener("click",Toolbar.onClick);
        }
        console.log(lockBtn.classList.contains('unlocked'));
    }
};

static onClick (event) {
    let dataAction = event.target.dataset.action;
    if (dataAction) {
        Toolbar[dataAction].action();
    }
};
```

Панель решил реализовать через класс. Кнопка блокировки - lock. Так как это не единственная кнопка, то вместо того, чтобы вешать на каждую кнопку разное событие решил решить проблему через делигирование событий методом onClick. Потом в коде повесил этот метод, как обработчик на всю панель.

```
 Toolbar.querySelector.addEventListener("click",Toolbar.onClick);
```

Почему-то при первом нажатии на кнопку lock она выполняет свою функцию корректно. А далее почему то срабатывает два раза (то есть вместо того чтобы разблокироватся - разблокируется и снова блокируется), увидел по логам консоли. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Потому что у вас не срабатывает удаление. [Как удалять lister'ы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453279/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7-dom/1453302#1453302) - посмотрите. В `removeEventListener` надо передать туже функцию, которая передавалась для `addEventListener`

Comment: Как раз таки removeEventListener присутствует в этом коде, прочтите внимательнее

Comment: ну значит два раза зашёл в одну и ту же ветку условия и навесил второй раз.... воспользуйтесь отладкой чтобы проверить куда идёт код каждый раз