# Проблема с Eventlistener

Tags: javascript, события

Пишу калькулятор.

[image]

На первом функции все работает хорошо, но когда вызывает вторая функция слушатель срабатывает два раза.
Как это можно решить или написать по другому?

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button')
const screen = document.querySelector('#screen')
let value1, value2
buttons.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (!isNaN(Number(el.innerHTML))) screen.value += el.innerHTML
        value1 = Number(screen.value)
        if (el.innerHTML === 'C') screen.value = ''
        switch (el.innerHTML) {
            case '+':
                operation(value1, '+')
                break
            case '-':
                operation(value1, '-')
                break
            case '*':
                operation(value1, '*')
                break
            case '/':
                operation(value1, '/')
                break
        }
    })
});

function operation(value1, operator) {
    buttons.forEach(el => {
        screen.value = ''
        el.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (!isNaN(Number(el.innerHTML))) screen.value += el.innerHTML
            value2 = Number(screen.value)
            if (el.innerHTML === 'C') screen.value = ''
            if (el.innerHTML === '=') {
                if (operator === '+') console.log(value1 + value2)
                else if (operator === '-') console.log(value1 - value2)
                else if (operator === '*') console.log(value1 * value2)
                else if (operator === '/') console.log(value1 / value2)
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Удаление с подтверждением из DOM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453279/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7-dom)

Comment: Более того скажу, каждое нажатие кнопки будет сопровождаться увеличением срабатываний. Почему так происходит, описывал в ответе по ссылке выше

Comment: @Dias, у тебя несколько раз навешивается событие на кнопки... Вешай один обработчик на весь калькулятор и там проверяй что именно нажали.
Приведи пример html - тогда можно будет показать более детально...