# Как удалить слушателя события?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Я вешаю слушателя события таким кодом:

```
import myFunction from '@/functions/myFunction'

document.addEventListener( 'click', (event) => { 
    myFunction(event, this.$el)
});
```

потому что мне в функции нужно передать само событие (event) и еще *this.$el*

Как я могу удалить этого слушателя? Пробовал так (не помогло):

```
document.removeEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

Comment: Очень интересно, ты повешал функцию на которую нет ни одной ссылки. Как же ты ее мог удалить?

Comment: Выше я эту функции импортирую так: `import myFunction from '@/functions/myFunction'`

Comment: Ты повешал не `myFunction`, а безымянную `(event) =>{ ... }`, теперь сообразил

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg а как ее обозначить чтобы мог ее удалить?

Comment: Ну все же очень просто, или вынеси `var handler = (event) =>{ ... }` и его удаляй, или сразу ставь `document.addEventListener( 'click', myFunction)` но приведи ее код к одному параметру события. Тем более `this.$el` ты можешь получить из `event.target`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg в `var handler = (event) =>{ ... }` я не могу получить `this.$el` ... а как  из `event.target` получить `this.$el` ?

Comment: Я не могу видеть, что это конкретно такое `this.$el`, а `event.target` это элемент по которому кликнули, его не надо получать - это он и есть. И пример с `const handler = (event) =>{ ... }` ничем не отличается от твоего примера, только лишь выносом ссылки для удаления, значит ты что-то еще делаешь не так.

Comment: Вот тут рассказывал, как [удалить обработчик события](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453279/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7-dom/1453302#1453302). Если коротко - необходимо в обработчик передавать именную функцию, а не анонимную. У вас анонимная.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос на самом деле в том, что именно вам нужно.

Если вы хотите не вызывать свою функцию при клике в зависимости от условия, то можете сделать это как то так:

```js
import myFunction from '@/functions/myFunction';

let clickHandlerEnabled = true;

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (clickHandlerEnabled) {
    myFunction(event, this.$el);
  }
});
```

Если же вам действительно нужно **удалить слушатель события**, то вам нужно указать **ссылку** на функцию, которую вы передали в метод `addEventListener`.

В вашем случае это анонимная функция, ссылка на которую нигде не сохранена.

Для достижения нужного вам поведения, вы можете сделать так:

```js
function myFunction(event, el) {
    console.log(this, event, el);
}

function handler(event) {
    myFunction.call(this, event, 'el');
}

document.addEventListener('click', handler);
document.removeEventListener('click', handler);
```

---

### Note

Просто на заметку, в приведенном вами коде:

```js
import myFunction from '@/functions/myFunction'

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
  myFunction(event, this.$el);
});
```

В this скорее всего не будет поля $el, т. к. вы используете стрелочную функцию.